# Status change notification from Zigbee IAS device

Tags: notifications, zigbee, smartthings

i have an xbee device and a smartthings multi purpose sensor.
and i'm developing a driver which acts like the smartthings hub.
I'm sure this multipurpose sensor is a IAS device.

In my code, i sent 
'write attribute request', 
'binding request', 
'match descriptor request', 
and 'enroll request' all of them with correct values,
and i received 00 success.

but the sensor never give me 'the status change notification' even I let the sensor detects something.

Is there missing in my code? or could you give me any helpful advice?
Thanks to read!

Answer (score 0):

You have to check with ZigBee sniffer what actually is happening on the ground. Look for any of the requests which come and the IAS device awaits a response to it. It may not be getting a response and the joining process remains incomplete and the end device leaves the network after the timeout.